# Why does not deploy Maven .war project to AWS?

Tags: java, spring, maven, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I have a problem with deploying .war project to the AWS (64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.2.0 running Tomcat 8 Java 8).

It is the Spring MVC project using Maven, and everything goes correct on my local Tomcat, but when I'm trying to deploy it to the AWS, and after deploying AWS shows that "Health" OK, but when try to open the site, it shows "page can’t be found" and in logs I have that:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat8/catalina.2016-12-08.log
-------------------------------------
 com.google.maps.internal.RateLimitExecutorService.run(RateLimitExecutorService.java:88)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
08-Dec-2016 09:50:38.524 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Dec-2016 09:50:38.526 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Dec-2016 09:50:38.526 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Dec-2016 09:50:38.527 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.157 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Aug 12 2016 18:14:42 UTC
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.36.0
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.16-27.56.amzn1.x86_64
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.24.amzn1.x86_64/jre
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_101-b13
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.161 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/share/tomcat8
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.162 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat8
<<<
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.163 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DAWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=****************
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.166 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DMY_S3_REGION=eu-central-1
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.170 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DJDBC_CONNECTION_STRING=
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.171 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.171 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024m
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.171 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms1024m
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.172 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat8
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.172 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.172 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.173 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.173 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat8/temp
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.173 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.173 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.173 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.393 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.430 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.443 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.448 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.449 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1258 ms
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.510 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.510 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
08-Dec-2016 09:50:42.538 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
08-Dec-2016 09:51:42.386 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
08-Dec-2016 09:51:42.407 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
08-Dec-2016 09:51:42.423 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
08-Dec-2016 09:51:42.424 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-14] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 com.google.maps.internal.RateLimitExecutorService.run(RateLimitExecutorService.java:88)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
08-Dec-2016 09:51:42.431 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT has finished in 59,892 ms
08-Dec-2016 09:51:42.434 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Dec-2016 09:51:42.439 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Dec-2016 09:51:42.440 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 59991 ms
08-Dec-2016 09:52:18.911 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
08-Dec-2016 09:52:18.911 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Dec-2016 09:52:18.913 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Dec-2016 09:52:18.913 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
08-Dec-2016 09:52:18.919 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Dec-2016 09:52:18.920 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Dec-2016 09:52:18.921 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Dec-2016 09:52:18.922 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.698 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Aug 12 2016 18:14:42 UTC
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.36.0
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.16-27.56.amzn1.x86_64
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.710 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.711 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.24.amzn1.x86_64/jre
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.711 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_101-b13
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.711 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.712 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/share/tomcat8
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.712 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat8
<<<
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.713 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DAWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=***************
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.713 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DMY_S3_REGION=eu-central-1
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.714 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DJDBC_CONNECTION_STRING=
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.714 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.714 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024m
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.718 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms1024m
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.719 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat8
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.719 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.719 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.720 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.720 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat8/temp
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.721 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.722 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.723 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
08-Dec-2016 09:52:22.959 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Dec-2016 09:52:23.000 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
08-Dec-2016 09:52:23.015 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Dec-2016 09:52:23.017 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
08-Dec-2016 09:52:23.018 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1306 ms
08-Dec-2016 09:52:23.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
08-Dec-2016 09:52:23.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
08-Dec-2016 09:52:23.106 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
08-Dec-2016 09:52:43.760 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT has finished in 20,653 ms
08-Dec-2016 09:52:43.767 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Dec-2016 09:52:43.775 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Dec-2016 09:52:43.782 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 20764 ms
```

If someone have some experience with can, can you help? 
Thanks

Comment: Is this something you're deploying to Elastic Beanstalk?  There is more logging information than you're showing - you only show the shutdown.   Can you grab more of the logs and update the post?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, added full logs @stdunbar

Comment: Add more logging as described in the following post: http://blog.trifork.com/2011/03/18/debugging-the-dreaded-severe-error-listenerstart-and-severe-error-filterstart-tomcat-error-messages/